# Error with md5 hash values

Tags: python, hash

I have typed the code for calculating the hash value of md5 and I want the hash values to return when the user click on a button. However, an error "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, function found" appear when I clicked the button. I tried converting the hash values to string but it didn't solve it.

```
def openfile():
filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
f = open(filename)
f.read()
print (filename)

def hashmd5():
md5 = hashlib.md5()
with open(openfile, "rb") as f:
for block in iter(lambda: f.read(128), ""):
md5.update(block)
print (m.hexdigest)

def helloCallBack():
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Calculate MD5")
B = Button(text ="Calculate MD5", command = hashmd5)
B.pack()
```

Update:

```
def openfile():
filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
f = open(filename)
f.read()
print (filename)

def savefile(self):
filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(**self.file_opt)
if filename:
return open(filename, 'w')

def hashmd5():
md5 = hashlib.md5()
with (filename), "rb") as f:
for block in iter(lambda: openfile.read(128), ""):
 md5.update(block)
 print (md5.hexdigest)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error: "NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined"  is because you did not defined filename in def hashmd5() function so you need to use self.filename in order to use filename variable

Answer (score 0):

Missing parentheses after `openfile`. But what's the point in opening the file twice? (Both in openfile and hashmd5?)

Comment: Pardon me. I didn't realized I left out the brackets. I removed the open file code in my hashmd5 function but Im still having errors after that.

Comment: What kind of errors? Please update the indentation of the snippet! I guess you wanted to `print md5.heaxidgest` instead `m.hexdigest`

Comment: okay. I've changed the code slightly. Im still having error "NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined"

Comment: Because you don't have filename defined in `def hashmd5():` and you are trying to access it `with (filename), "rb") as f:` You should pass it over as an argument. Fix the indentation please!